# Cannot Insert the value Null into column printed - insert fails

Tags: sql-server

I have the following stored proc given to me which is used to insert into     the table below using a web application. When you hit submit on the form I am getting the following error.

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Printed', table 'CAB.dbo.Participants'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

I have traced the proc and have gotten the following

```
declare @p20 int
set @p20=NULL
exec sp_AddParticipant @P_FirstName='John ',@P_MI='m',@P_LastName='French',@P_Company='',@P_Email='jfrench1941@gmail.com',@P_Address='10045 Hampton Rd',@P_City='Sacramento ',@P_State='ca',@P_Zip='95864',@P_Phone='917-349-9845',@Gift=0,@P_Age='',@P_Education='',@P_Income='',@P_Commmethod='Email',@CC_Ty    pe='Visa',@CC_Name='John   French',@CC_Number='4822820089199876',@CC_Expires='12/19',@ID=@p20 output
    select @p20
    go

    Any help would be much appreciated.

    SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddParticipant]
    @P_FirstName varchar(20),
    @P_MI varchar(5)= Null,
    @P_LastName varchar(30),
    @P_Company varchar(80)= Null,
    @P_Email varchar(50),
    @P_Address varchar(40),
    @P_City varchar(40),
    @P_State varchar(15),
    @P_Zip varchar(10),
    @P_Phone varchar(25),
    @Gift bit, 
    @GiftType varchar(10) = Null,
    @G_FirstName varchar(20)= Null,
    @G_MI varchar(5)= Null,
    @G_LastName varchar(30)= Null,
    @G_Company varchar(80)= Null,
    @G_Email varchar(50)= Null,
    @G_Address varchar(40)= Null,
    @G_City varchar(40)= Null,
    @G_State varchar(15)= Null,
    @G_Zip varchar(10)= Null,
    @G_Phone varchar(25)= Null, 
    @P_Age varchar(20)= Null,
    @P_Education varchar(20)= Null,
    @P_Income varchar(20)= Null,
    @P_Commmethod varchar(10)= Null,
    @CC_Type varchar(25),
    @CC_Name varchar(50),
    @CC_Number varchar(16),
    @CC_Expires varchar(7),
    @ID bigint OUTPUT

        AS
    INSERT INTO Participants
    (P_FIRSTNAME,P_MI,P_LASTNAME,P_COMPANY,P_EMAIL,P_ADDRESS,P_CITY,P_STATE,P        _ZIP,P_PHONE,GIFT,GIFTTYPE,
    G_FIRSTNAME,G_MI,G_LASTNAME,G_COMPANY,G_EMAIL,G_ADDRESS,G_CITY,G_STATE,G_        ZIP,G_PHONE,P_AGE,P_EDUCATION,
    P_INCOME,P_COMMMETHOD,CC_TYPE,CC_NAME,CC_NUMBER,CC_EXPIRES)
    VALUES
    (@P_FIRSTNAME,@P_MI,@P_LASTNAME,@P_COMPANY,@P_EMAIL,@P_ADDRESS,@P_CITY,@P        _STATE,@P_ZIP,@P_PHONE,@GIFT,@GIFTTYPE,
    @G_FIRSTNAME,@G_MI,@G_LASTNAME,@G_COMPANY,@G_EMAIL,@G_ADDRESS,@G_CITY,@G_        STATE,@G_ZIP,@G_PHONE,@P_AGE,@P_EDUCATION,
    @P_INCOME,@P_COMMMETHOD,@CC_TYPE,@CC_NAME,@CC_NUMBER,@CC_EXPIRES)

    SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY
```

Comment: Well you don't have the `Printed` column in your insert statement so it will try to insert null, since that column doesn't allow nulls, you get that error. What more is there to explain here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the `Printed` field is a new field in the table which has a `NOT NULL` constraint and doesn't have a default value set. This procedure doesn't seem to attempt to insert data into that field and since it can't insert `NULL` the insert fails.

Review recent changes to the table, try to work out how to change the procedure to insert the correct value into that field.